# Gradient in jQuery slide does not stay in place?

Tags: jquery, css, gradient, slide

I am puzzling with a gradient inside a jQuery slide, so the gradient only becomes visible when a link is clicked. Which also works – my problem is that the gradient does not fill the entire wrapper that is placed in, but leaves a small gap top and bottom.

Here is an example link: http://itu.dk/people/akam/test_gradient/

As you can see the green background colour of the #wrapper is visible in top and bottom after the slide is opened and showing the gradient - how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#color_box pre { 
    margin:0; 
    /* everything else */ 
}
```

There is a usual browser stylesheet with a `margin` on `<pre>`.

Answer (score 1):

Give "margin:0" in #color_box pre.